Multiple-codepoint emoji
I'm trying to include UTF-8 emoji's like "Woman Kneeling" (‍♀️) in a XeLaTeX document.
Unlike single-codepoint emoji's such as Winking Face with Tongue () which has only one unicode point (U+1F61C), the multi-codepoint emoji above is composed of several unicode points: Kneeling Person (U+1F9CE) Zero Width Joiner (U+200D) and Female Sign (U+2640 U+FE0F).
In the MWE (compiled with XeLaTeX) below, only the Segoe UI Emoji font is rendered correctly.
MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

Single-codepoint emoji: \fbox{\fontspec{Noto Color Emoji} }

Single-codepoint emoji: \fbox{\fontspec{Twemoji Mozilla} }

Single-codepoint emoji: \fbox{\fontspec{Segoe UI Emoji} }

Multiple-codepoint emoji: \fbox{\fontspec{Noto Color Emoji} ‍♀️}

Multiple-codepoint emoji: \fbox{\fontspec{Twemoji Mozilla} ‍♀️}

Multiple-codepoint emoji: \fbox{\fontspec{Segoe UI Emoji} ‍♀️}

\end{document}

Output

And I'm getting the following messages:
Missing character: There is no   in font Twemoji Mozilla!
Missing character: There is no   in font Twemoji Mozilla/OT!
Missing character: There is no   in font Twemoji Mozilla/OT:script=DFLT;languag
e=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no   in font Twemoji Mozilla/OT:script=DFLT;languag
e=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no   in font Twemoji Mozilla/OT:script=DFLT;languag
e=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ∩╕Å in font Noto Color Emoji/OT:script=latn;langua
ge=dflt;!

I'm using Windows 10 and I've verified that both Noto Color Emoji and Twemoji Mozilla are installed under the C:\Windows\Fonts folder. I've also tested the above emoji fonts in a Word document (screenshot below). Again, only Segoe UI Emoji is rendered correctly; Noto basically shows up as blanks; and Twemoji incorrectly displays the multi-codepoint emoji.

Questions

What's the most likely reason for the incorrect rendering of Noto and Twemoji fonts?
If I'm stuck with the Segoe UI Emoji font, can XeLaTeX turn the emoji's into colored ones as they appear in the Word document?


First of all: if the glyph does not show in Word, in can be a hint that the font just does not contains it. Apart from that, there are different formats of emoji fonts, and not all of them are available for use with XeLaTeX as far as I know

If you look at the shape of the "female" emoji in the screenshot you show, you can see that it has a black outline which makes me assume that this is the glyph taken from Segoe UI Emoji as replacement as the other fonts don't provide it. Therefore, I would conclude that Twemoji Mozilla does not support the ligature for "kneeling female person". Since the row with Noto Color Emoji does not show any glyphs at all (except from the "female" emoji which is, however, obviously not from this font), there might be a problem with the font in general.

So, in conclusion: The ligature to form "kneeling female person" seems to work with XeLaTeX and Segoe UI Emoji, so it is very likely a font related issue and not an issue with XeLaTeX. You should double-check that the font can be used with XeLaTeX (see these explanations on Overleaf about the use of color (emoji) fonts) and that it provides the glyph you want to use. Note that Word often silently changes the font if a glyph is unavailable.

@JasperHabicht: Thank you very much for the comment. The Overleaf article looks very helpful. I'll have to read it in more detail to get a better understanding.
